# Linux and iscsi multipath

Tags: multipath-storage

My goal is to make,for testing purpose
a multipath lvm iscsi
I have setup two debian
iscsi server,workings
I have setup the multipath on
a debian client and i can
create dirs,etc on ext4 fs.
But if server1 goes down
the fs is stucked(hang)
Why?
This is my multipath.conf

```
defaults {
         udev_dir                /dev
         polling_interval        5
         path_grouping_policy    multibus
         path_checker            directio
         prio                    const
         rr_min_io               100
         rr_weight               priorities
         failback                immediate
         no_path_retry           fail
}

blacklist {
         devnode "^(ram|sda|raw|loop|fd|md|dm-|sr|scd|st)[0-9]*"
         devnode "^hd[a-z][[0-9]*]"
         devnode "^vd[a-z]"
         devnode "^cciss!c[0-9]d[0-9]*[p[0-9]*]"
}

multipaths {
         multipath {
                 wwid 149455400000000009d1b03a0217052c8b19b0fa6e5bfe7bd
                 alias iscsi_storage
         }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: not possible

[Dual-primary DRBD, iSCSI, and multipath: Don’t Do That!](https://fghaas.wordpress.com/2011/11/29/dual-primary-drbd-iscsi-and-multipath-dont-do-that/)

> “Dual-primary” iSCSI targets for multipath: does not work. iSCSI is a
>   stateful protocol, there is more to it that than just reads and
>   writes. To run multipath (or multi-connections per session) against
>   distinct targets on separate nodes you’d need to have cluster aware
>   iSCSI targets which coordinate with each other in some fashion. To my
>   knowledge, this does not exist (not for Linux, anyways).